# Bootstrap Datepicker with AngularJS Update Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to update the date field to the database from an Angular page.  I am not able to bind the modified date to the database.  The item.ReimbDatehas the old value.

I am using a bootstrap datepicker.

`<input type="text" class="datepicker input-small date" ng-model="item.ReimbDate" id="ReimbDate" name="ReimbDate" placeholder=""/>`

Can someone help me out in fixing this issue.

Note: I am new to Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to roll your own directive that "plays nice" with ng-model as described in the bottom of this page:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

> In order for custom control to work with ngModel and to achieve
>   two-way data-binding it needs to:
>
> implement $render method, which is responsible for rendering the data
>   after it passed the NgModelController#$formatters, call $setViewValue
>   method, whenever the user interacts with the control and model needs
>   to be updated. This is usually done inside a DOM Event listener.

or use one like this:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

**EDIT**
Here's another write up on creating custom directives for non-angular libraries to integrate their functionality:
http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when using an older version of AngularJS, but it appears to be fixed in version 1.2.3 and later.

It's related to `input` fields not reacting to change events.  An easy fix is just to upgrade to AngularJS v1.2.3 or later.  Here's the [changelog for that release](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#123-unicorn-zapper-2013-11-27).